# Are these @Table(uniqueConstraints) and @Table(indexes) annotations the same?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-annotations, database-indexes, jpa-annotations

When creating indexes in JPA / Hibernate, are these exactly the same?

```
@Table (uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint (columnNames = {"series", "date"}))
```

And:

```
@Table (indexes = {@Index (name = "idx", columnList = "series, date", unique = true)})
```

And if not, what's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

Both `@UniqueConstraint`  and `@Index` are just hints for the schema generation tool, which is dialect/DB sensitive. Your specific example will likely produce the same index ddl for most DB providers.  General difference between the two is that you can index a column without enforcing uniqueness. And of course, both are irrelevant if you do not generate your schema with JPA/hibernate schema gen. If you need more control over your indexes or schema in general, you might want to consider tools like liquibase or flywheel.

Comment: I like to use both JPA annotations and liquibase in order to double check the schema correctness